# htaccess to remove specific query string from url

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the URL

```
http://example.com/index.php?err=true&i=1
```

The `i` value changes 1 to 3. I want to transform that URL into this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?err=true
```

Whenever the query string parameter `i` is found in the URL, the `i` has to be removed from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule to remove parameter `i` from the query string from any position:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?i=[^&]*&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=308,NE,L]
```

Comment: ok use my updated rule after clearing browser cache. `308` preserves `POST` data. Here `%1` represents query string before `i=` parameter and `%2` represents query string after `i` parameter. `%{REQUEST_URI}` is your complete input URI.

Comment: Sorry, that is a separate question and independent of this problem. Once this problem is solved you may post a separate question.